# Angular.js - ng-repeat not showing updated array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I have got code that reads the data from the array perfectly when I use a AJAX request. When I push an object to the array however, ng-repeat doesn't render the new row and I have to refresh the page to then fetch the data that was sent to server.

Why does it do this?
Thanks

### Javascript

```
function processError() {
        var responseCode = 404;
        var error = {};
        error["client"] = document.getElementById('client').value;
        error["errorMessage"] = document.getElementById('error-message').value;
        error["simpleRes"] = document.getElementById('simple-fix').value;
        error["fullRes"] = document.getElementById('full-fix').value;
        error["reason"] = document.getElementById('reason').value;

        var errorJson = JSON.stringify(error);

        $.ajax({
            url: "../ErrorChecker/rest/error",
            type: "POST",
            data: errorJson,
            contentType: "application/json"
        })
            .done(function (data, statusText, xhr, displayMessage) {
                $('.form').hide();
                responseCode = xhr.status;
                reloadData(data);
            });

        function reloadData(data) {
            if (responseCode == 200) {
                processPositiveResponse(data);
            } else {
                $('#negative-message').show(1000);
            }
        }
    }

function processPositiveResponse(data) {
        $('#positive-message').show(1000);
        updateTable(data);
        $('#errorTable').DataTable().destroy();
        setupTable();
        clearInputs();
        console.log($scope.controller.errors);
    }

function updateTable(data) {
        $scope.controller.errors.push({
            "id": data,
            "client": document.getElementById('client').value,
            "errorMessage": document.getElementById('error-message').value,
            "simpleRes": document.getElementById('simple-fix').value,
            "fullRes": document.getElementById('full-fix').value,
            "reason": document.getElementById('reason').value
        })
    }
```

### HTML

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in dataCtrl.errors">
        <td class="collapsing">
            <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <label></label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="display: none">{{ x.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.client }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.errorMessage }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.simpleRes }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.fullRes }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.reason }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: more about why you [shouldn't use jQuery with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're using jQuery and Angular together. Don't do that. EVER. Angular is not aware of what jQuery is doing, and jQuery is not aware of what Angular is generating in the DOM. Solution : REMOVE jQuery and use Angular's own `$http` service.

The same way, don't use `document.getElementById('full-fix').value`. You're taking Angular backwards. Angular *generates* the DOM from data, so you don't need to *select* DOM elements to read their value because that value is already in your data.

Answer (score -1):

Update the document. Use scope apply as a quick fix. Not the way to do it imo. But it will solve your problem fast. On my mobile if I do not forget ill update this comment later with more details and best practises. For now a google search to scope apply will help you a long way.